# How to compare (get difference) between two pcap files?

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap

I am testing Firewalls for Clients using Scapy. I Create pcap files with packets, representing all given permit and denys of the Firewall. I sniff the incoming traffic and now i want to automate a comparison between the two pcap files, instead of reading them manually. Is there any easy way to compare these files with wireshark or scapy?
If not, what would you suggest to get the result i want? I thought of creating lists which i could compare to each other, but i would like to leave the packets in pcap format if possible.

I tried pcap-diff and Wirediff, but i didnt get the results I wanted/needed. In theorie, I only want to know which packets where dropped at the Firewall, to see if everything was configured the right way.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We could simply use `rdpcap` of `scapy` with a little script

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap1 = rdpcap("file1.pcap")
pcap2 = rdpcap("file2.pcap")

for packet1 in pcap1:
    if packet1 not in pcap2:
        print(f"Packet {packet1.summary()} from file1.pcap was dropped")
```